# Invoking Photoshop filters (desaturation, resizing, change palette) from C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, photoshop

I need to programmatically process some images using C#, and to match the results that our design team is achieving I would prefer to use Photoshop.

Is there a way to apply the filters mentioned in the title in the same way you would by using Photoshop's GUI, but through C#?

Answer (score 1):

well personally havent tried it programmatically but maybe this one: http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/ might help you. Its basically an old reference, but give it a try it might still be valid. Otherwise, spend a few minutes to go through the page there: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Will take some time for me to actually try this out - not much of my time is allocated to this project. I will however come back to this question once the matter is settled.